# How to add class to parent when child is visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a menu with a sub menu, when the sub menu is visible I want to add a class to parent list element.

```html
<ul class="upper-menu">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li class="parent-li">Item 3
    <ul class="lower-menu">
      <li>Sub Item 1</li>
      <li>Sub Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Basically, when the "lower-menu" is visible, I want to add another class to the list element "parent-li". Also when the lower-menu is not visible, I want to the remove the class from "parent-li". Is this possible in JQuery?

Thanks

Comment: Well what makes the submenu visible or invisible …?

Comment: I am initially setting the sub menu to hidden by using $("lower-menu").hide(). Then when "parent-li" is clicked, I use slideToggle to open and close the sub menu.

Comment: So where is the problem in adding the class to the parent at that point then …?

Comment: How would I toggle the class though? When the li is clicked, I want to add the class, and when it is clicked again, I want to remove the class.

Comment: On click you can check if the element has that class, if it does, remove it, else add it.

Comment: Thanks! That was actually super easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the desired element by `:visible` pseudo class and then assign your class to its parent:

```js
$(".lower-menu:visible").closest('.parent-li').addClass("test");
```

```css
.test {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="upper-menu">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li class="parent-li">Item 3
    <ul class="lower-menu">
      <li>Sub Item 1</li>
      <li>Sub Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Going through the DOM Tree with "parent()" is really tricky. Szenario: You change your layout in a couple of months, for instance you wrapp the `ul.lower-menu`  in a div, for design purposes. You will need to rework your script since parent is not the direct parent anymore.

Comment: @CristianS. -- thanks for pointing out. Updated the code. Now it searches through the parents until it finds a `.parent-li`.

Comment: .closest() would be better here as it travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector then stops while .parents() travels up to the DOM root.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by following jquery script

```
if($('.lower-menu').is(':visible')){
    $(this).parent().addClass("YourClass");
 }
```